# Show a div pertaining to a certain id?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So when I run the following code, I click on a div, and another div slides out.

```
<div class="section" id="1">Hi</div>
<div class="under" id="1">Hola</div>
<div class="section" id="2">Foo bar</div>
<div class="under" id="2">Derp</div>
</td></table>
</td></table>

<script>
$(".section").click(function(){
var id = this.id;
    $(".under").slideToggle("slow");
  });
```

But, when I click on the div with the class "section", it shows ALL of the divs with the class "under." What I want to do is show the div "under" with an id that is equal to the id of the div selected (i.e. show "under" with id="1" when "section" with id="1" is clicked). How would I do this?

Comment: You should not be using numeric-only `id` attributes. I hear in newer versions of HTML it may be allowed, but I would refrain at least for now.

Comment: What definitely isn't allowed is more than one element with the same id, and you are storing up all kinds of problems for the future by having them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use

```
.next('div');
```

so whole code would be

```
<style> 
   .under{ 
      display:none; 
 padding:5px; 
     background-color:gray; 
    } 
</style> 
<div class="section" id="1">Hi</div> 
<div class="under" id="1">Hola</div> 
<div class="section" id="2">Foo bar</div> 
<div class="under" id="2">Derp</div> 
<script> 
$(".section").click(function(){ 

    $(this).next('div').slideToggle("slow"); 
  }); 
</script>
```

[working demo](http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/00fa1/1)

Comment: Yes, sorry, I had to eat dinner :3

Answer (score 0):

You can use .next, or depending on how you have things setup, .nextAll. Here is a short demo i did for a question similar to this:

http://jsfiddle.net/andresilich/AeGSQ/

Answer (score 0):

Ok there are a few things wrong with your HTML; I will go through them one by one.

1. There is no opening `<table>` or `<td>` tag. This will result in invalid HTML.
2. There should be a `<tr>` tag containing the `td` tag. It is structurally incorrect as it is at the moment.
3. I am thinking you're using tables for layout; tables should be used for data-display only, not for page layout.
4. You have multiple ids the same. The idea of an id is that it identifies one element and one element only. Classes are used to style multiple elements the same.

I have rewritten your code at http://jsfiddle.net/FS3rt/. It also contracts any visible sections so that the user is presented only with the information they would like to see.

Comment: um.. what's with the downvote? My answer is a perfectly valid, working solution and I have also pointed out a few mistakes in the code. What's wrong with doing that? People will never learn unless others take the time to point out their mistakes.

Comment: do not think about it. Somebody downvote my one too, however I think it's perfect too. I don't think we can do much about it

Comment: Yeah it was probably just a 'surf-by downvoter', so to speak. It ought to be compulsory to leave a comment.